# error with cyclic autocorrelation function

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm trying to code a  [cyclic autocorrelation function](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-cyclic-autocorrelation-function) in matlab as follows:

```
t=0:(N-1);
t=t*Te;
i_alpha=0;
tau=-N2*Te:Te:N2*Te;
alpha=-1/2:1/N:1/2;
Ryy_cl=zeros(length(alpha),length(tau));
for alpha=alpha/Te
    ind_tau=0;
    i_alpha=i_alpha+1;
    for k=tau
        ind_tau=ind_tau+1;

    if k>0
 %             Ryy_cl(i_alpha,ind_tau)=1/length(sig_bin_syl_mod(1:end-   k))*sum((sig_bin_syl_mod(1:end-k)).*sig_bin_syl_mod(k+1:end)).*exp(1i*2*pi*alpha*t(1+k:length(sig_bin_syl_mod(1:end))));
              Ryy_cl(i_alpha,ind_tau)=(1/N)*sum((sig_bin_syl_mod(1:end-k)).*sig_bin_syl_mod(k+1:end)).*exp(-1i*2*pi*alpha*t(1:end-k));

        else
           Ryy_cl(i_alpha,ind_tau)=(1/N)*sum((sig_bin_syl_mod(1-k:end)).*sig_bin_syl_mod(1:end+k)).*exp(-1i*2*pi*alpha*t(1-k:end));
       end

    end
end
```

I'm getting errors, and it doesn't really show what I am expecting. According to the below formulae, how can I fix it?
[image: math_formulae]

Comment: What error is  there?

Comment: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is incomplete, so it is difficult to confidently reproduce your error. In particular, you haven't defined the signal (sig_bin_syl_mod), the sampling increment (Te), or the signal length (N).

I get different errors depending on how I choose Te. The simplest thing to do is choose Te = 1. But that isn't realistic. A 1-MHz sampling rate would have Te = 1.0e-6.

When Te is not an integer, you can see that one problem is that tau will not be an integer, yet you are assigning k to tau, then using k as an index.

So your code has basic problems.

Now I'm going to answer your question directly. Rewrite the code, breaking the product above into separate steps so you can debug it more easily.

First, don't try to get the CA for all tau and alpha in one shot. Focus on getting the function correct for a single cycle frequency alpha and all tau. 
I've put together quite a few helpful posts on exactly how to do this on cyclostationary.wordpress.com.

Second, put the corrected single-alpha code in a loop. Then try to make it efficient.

By the way, a very efficient alternate way to estimate the cyclic autocorrelation is to first construct the cyclic periodogram (see my website) and then inverse Fourier transform it. This harnesses the power of the FFT.

Finally, that link to Quora discusses a different "cyclic autocorrelation". You are trying to do cyclostationary signal processing, but that link deals only with the DFT/FFT and circular shifts thereof. See my website for the definition and properties of the cyclic autocorrelation of interest to you.

Chad

Comment: thanks for your asnwer, i have tried also to plot the CAF with FFT/DFT as we can get the CA by DFT(x(t)*x(t+tau)), but did not get significant resulat

Comment: the signal  (sig_bin_syl_mod) is a BPSK signal with Te=5e-6, according to the model i have.

Comment: I meant estimating the CAF by performing an inverse Fourier transform of the cyclic periodogram: Rx(tau,alpha) = IFFT (X(f+alpha/2) X^*(f-alpha/2)). This might be a bit easier for you to program. First make sure your code works for alpha=0, which is just IFFT (X(f)X^*(f)), the normal autocorrelation function. Then move on to alpha =/= 0.

Comment: thank you very mush for your help, that was very useful